# Need to get the view reference of newly added item in recyclerview

Tags: android, listview

I am novice in android and whatever I have learned that all from youtube (slidenerd tutorials). I am working on a social app, there I have implemented recyclerview to show the list of post in the home activity. It's working fine.

Here is my question:

In my recyclerview, there is a cardview, inside that all elements are existing and there is a share button. I need to implement action on share button so that when user clicks on the button a new item should be added in the recyclerview. This one also I have done and it's also working fine. **When the item added in the list, I need to get it's view reference, to change the color of my textview.**

I searched a lot regarding the same and tried so many solutions but didn't get the proper output.

Please comment on the same and let me know if any further information is needed.

Comment: Please share the code you've tried.

Comment: Is it the a textview contained in the newly added item that needs to change color?

Comment: Yes there is textview that I need to change the color once the post is shared. For this I need the view reference so that I can write code on OnClickListener of the share button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RecyclerView needs RecyclerView.Adapter, and the Adapter's onBindViewHolder will be called after new view was added.

My suggestion is: How about check new view in onBindViewHolder?

For example, In your RecyclerView.Adapter,

```
private ArrayList<ItemData> itemsData;
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

    // itemsData is ArrayList of ItemData.
    if (position == itemsData.length() -1) { // Newly added view may be last item of list.
        // Write your code here.
        ItemData data = itemsData.get(position);
        viewHolder.txtViewTitle.setTextColor(Color.BLUE); 
    } else {
        // Edit1:
        viewHolder.txtViewTitle.setTextColor(/* Default color */); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I used this code just now, it's working but not properly like if I have 5 items and when 6th item is added , code change the color of 6 th item as well as 3 or 4 th item randomly. I am not getting the reason for this. It seems this is very tricky.

Comment: RecyclerView recycles it's own list item. It seems that you need to set default text color if it is not a last item. See Edit 1. If you show me your actual code, I can find actual point to modify.

Comment: Thank you so much Stanley, it's working. I worked on this for two days but I was not getting the flow of execution. You saved me and my time too. Thanks again.